# Using IF condtion with comparison operator stored in variable

Tags: php, html, web

I have set of rules which involves comparison operators. I want to do some task based on the value of comparison operator stored in the rule. I am doing it in the following way but it is not working. Check the following code

```
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Greater than')
    $comparison='>';
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Equal to')
    $comparison='==';
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Less than')
    $comparison='<';

if($value['1'].$comparison.$value[$i]['2']){
    debug('Condtion checked');
}
```

problem is it always checks the condition to be true. it takes whole parameter inside IF condition to be string so as long as that string is not empty is executes the code inside the parenthesis.
Please help me here.

Comment: Firstly, `Equal to` is `==` not just one `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It always evaluates to true as you're simply evaluating the existence of a string (you can't construct logical statements in this manner in PHP).

To achieve what you're attempting, you'd need to either use a switch statement (where you simply have a one to one match for each potential comparison operator) like so...

```
switch ($comparison) {
    case '<': { if($value['1'] < $value[$i]['2']) { ... } break; }
    case '==': { if($value['1'] == $value[$i]['2']) { ... } break; }
    case '>': { if($value['1'] > $value[$i]['2']) { ... } break; }
}
```

...or use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to parse the logic. If might seem like a no-brainer to use the eval approach, but as the PHP manual admits:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

As such, if you don't understand the risks involved, **please stick with the switch approach**. That said, a basic solution using eval would resemble the following:

```
eval('return ' . $value['1'] . $comparison . $value[$i]['2'] . ';');
```

Comment: Of all the answers given, i think switch approach is most appropriate and basic. Thanks to all

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you're trying to use string as a code without evaluating it. You can use [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) like this:

```
$sCondition = '<';
$mData0     = 4;
$mData1     = 5.5;
$fnCallback=create_function('$x, $y', 'return $x'.$sCondition.'$y;');
var_dump($fnCallback($mData0, $mData1)); // true
```

Alternatively, there is an [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function, but it seems direct returning will be more useful in your case.

Comment: This is a much better approach than using eval.

Comment: @middaparka Though, `create_function()` behaves pretty much the same as `eval()` :)

Comment: Yes, it is. The only advantage that we can use direct call (no need to create temporary variable).

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "$result = (bool)($value['1'] $comparison $value[$i]['2']);";
eval($str);
if($result){
  //true
}
```

You can use eval(), but this also works:

```
            if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Greater than'){
              $comparison = (bool)($value['1'] > $value[$i]['2']);
            }

            if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Equal to'){
              $comparison = (bool)($value['1'] == $value[$i]['2']);
            }

            if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Less than'){
              $comparison = (bool)($value['1'] < $value[$i]['2']);
            }

            if($comparison){
                debug('Condtion checked');
            }
```

**EDIT**

This looks better

Comment: code in the form if ($x) { $y=true; } else { $y=false; } is highly redundant, simply write $y=(bool)$x;

Answer (score 1):

This kind of construct is not possible without some kind of magic, either `create_function()` or `eval()`.

However, you can also use a closure to achieve what you want; return a comparison function based on the operator that you want to use. You could consider this a cheap version of the Strategy pattern:

```
function getComparisonFunction($operator)
{
    // comparison function is returned
    return function($a, $b) use ($operator) {
        if ($operator == 'Greater than') {
            return $a > $b;
        } elseif ($operator == 'Equal to') {
            return $a == $b;
        } else { // Less than
            return $a < $b;
        }
    }
}
// get comparison function
$fn = getComparisonFunction($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']);

// use comparison function
if ($fn($value['1'], $value[$i]['2'])) {
    debug('Condtion checked');
}
```

Comment: Probably the perfect solution, if you're running PHP 5.3 and above.

Comment: @middaparka Yeah, but 5.3 has been around for 4+ years :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Greater than')
    $comparison='>';
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Equal to')
    $comparison='==';
if($benRules[$i]['amountCriteria']=='Less than')
    $comparison='<';

eval('$bool = $value[\'1\']'.$comparison.'$value[$i][\'2\'];');

if($bool){
    debug('Condtion checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval` function

```
if (eval('return '.$value['1'].$comparison.$value[$i]['2'].';')){

}
```

Comment: The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code..See documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: knives are also dangerous yet you use them, don't you? If one uses it reasonably, it is a powerfull and interesting tool. Here, we have a $comparison taken from switch, if one also casts $value[$i] so it has to contain just numbers it is a 100% safe code.